# Capistrano run method before every other task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have sort of a weird requirement in capistrano.

There is one particular method i need to execute before every other custom task runs. Is there any way to do this.

I want to do something like this

```
def master_def
 ...
 ...
 return boolean
end

before_every_task: master_def

task :t1 do
  # master_def must run first
  ...
end
task :t2 do
  # master_def must run first
  ...
end
```

And i use capistrano 2.15.4

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that that's possible with a Capistrano command but here is a full list of the commands.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks

I think you will have to prioritize that method in your code not by using a specific Capistrano command.